# Does iOS 5 handle low-memory situations differently?

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, ios5, didreceivememorywarning

I'm having an issue in iOS 5.0 only, where low-memory warnings received while a modal view is present can sometimes leave me with a white screen - I believe this happens because my tab bar controller releases all of its views.

The same scenarios don't cause a problem in iOS 4.0. There are two explanations I can think of:

1. iOS 5 uses more RAM, leaving less for the app
2. iOS 5 treats low-memory situations differently

In versions before 5.0, I used to be able to respond to a low-memory warning by freeing up some additional memory. In 5.0, it seems like the first time I get a low-memory warning, everything under my modal view controller clears its view. Tracing confirms that, after a memory warning, any controllers under the modal view controller have their `view` field set to `nil`.

Can anyone point me to information (ideally from Apple) about how iOS 5 handles low-memory situations vs. earlier versions? I'd like to be able to free up some memory when necessary instead of having all my views cleared out.

Comment: I don't know if that's really the case, but did you implement -(void)viewDidLoad so that all the views are loaded or set up there?

Comment: You should really use viewDidLoad and viewDidUnload for setting up your views and for releasing them.

Comment: "The same scenarios don't cause a problem in iOS 5.0." Did you mean iOS 4.0?

Comment: @Till, EmilioPelaez, I think the problem is worse than my views being built poorly. My tab bar controller is sometimes completely removed from the screen and, at other times, my navigation controllers are reset back to their root (probably because they've been removed from the tab bar controller and rebuilt). So just being able to rebuild my views isn't enough, because by unloading my nav controllers and tab controllers, I end up in a "fresh" state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In answer to the question in your last paragraph, you are looking for the *iOS Performance in Depth* video from [WWDC 2011](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2011/).  It discusses low-memory handling in iOS 5 starting around 13 or 14 minutes in, and discusses changes to the low-memory warning message specifically starting around 16 minutes in.

I'm not sure it will help you figure out what's going wrong with your app though.

Comment: do you mean "iOS Performance and Power Optimization with Instruments"? I don't see one specifically named "iOS Performance in Depth"

Comment: Hmm.  I can't find it on the web site either.  In iTunes U, it's session 318.  https://deimos.apple.com/WebObjects/Core.woa/BrowsePrivately/adc.apple.com.8266478284.08266478290.8365294549?i=1534533040

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same issue and fixed it. The problem is that the outlets that we connect via xib are set to nil in viewDidUnload method. This method is called on all views that are not currently visible, when memory warning occurs. When we come back to those views, their viewDidLoad method is called again. The only way to fix this is to remove setNil methods from viewDIdUnload to dealloc method and everything will work fine.